# How to print Javascript data Array inside object

Tags: javascript, object

I have details of the students; how to get my expected output? In one object I want the name of the student as key and an array of their car names as value

```js
let empArray = [{
    "name": "soma",
    "cars Details": [{
      "name": "audi",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }, {
      "name": "toyota",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }],
    "salary": 40000
  },
  {
    "name": "steven",
    "cars Details": [{
      "name": "bmw",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }],
    "salary": 70000
  },
  {
    "name": "booth",
    "cars Details": [{
      "name": "swift",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }, {
      "name": "audi",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }],
    "salary": 35000
  },
]

let a = {}
var ids = [];
for (let i = 0; i < empArray.length; i++) {
  a = empArray[i]["cars Details"]
  console.log(a)
}
```

**Expected Output**

```js
{soma :["audi","toyota"],steven:["bmw"],booth:["swift","audi"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let empArray = [{ "name": "soma", "cars Details": [{ "name": "audi", "cost": 120000, "Speed": "150Km/hr" }, { "name": "toyota", "cost": 120000, "Speed": "150Km/hr" }], "salary": 40000 }, { "name": "steven", "cars Details": [{ "name": "bmw", "cost": 120000, "Speed": "150Km/hr" }], "salary": 70000 }, { "name": "booth", "cars Details": [{ "name": "swift", "cost": 120000, "Speed": "150Km/hr" }, { "name": "audi", "cost": 120000, "Speed": "150Km/hr" }], "salary": 35000 },]

let dict = {}
empArray.forEach((e) => {
  dict[e.name] = e["cars Details"].map((car) => {
    return car.name
  })
})

console.log(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) to do:

```js
// input
let empArray = [{
    "name": "soma",
    "cars Details": [{
      "name": "audi",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }, {
      "name": "toyota",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }],
    "salary": 40000
  },
  {
    "name": "steven",
    "cars Details": [{
      "name": "bmw",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }],
    "salary": 70000
  },
  {
    "name": "booth",
    "cars Details": [{
      "name": "swift",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }, {
      "name": "audi",
      "cost": 120000,
      "Speed": "150Km/hr"
    }],
    "salary": 35000
  },
];

const output = empArray.reduce((outObj, item) => {
  outObj[item.name] = item['cars Details'].map(detail => detail.name);
  return outObj
}, {});

// test
console.log(output)
```

By the way, if you can, I'd recommend avoiding object keys containing spaces and change `cars Details` to `carsDetails`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let empArray=[{name:"soma","cars Details":[{name:"audi",cost:12e4,Speed:"150Km/hr"},{name:"toyota",cost:12e4,Speed:"150Km/hr"}],salary:4e4},{name:"steven","cars Details":[{name:"bmw",cost:12e4,Speed:"150Km/hr"}],salary:7e4},{name:"booth","cars Details":[{name:"swift",cost:12e4,Speed:"150Km/hr"},{name:"audi",cost:12e4,Speed:"150Km/hr"}],salary:35e3}];

let result = empArray.reduce((acc,e) => ({[e.name]:e['cars Details'].map(n => n.name),...acc}), {} )

console.log(result)
```